# ASPNET CORE - Can I add a ControllerModel in a IApplicationModelConvention?

Tags: asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to add controllers dynamically, the catch is that their actions are also dynamic, so I can't simply use a generic controller.

I dug through msdn and found that overriding the method `Apply@IApplicationModelConvention` seems to be my best option. However, the controller I add is never found by the routing system.

This is what I tried:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {


            services.AddMvc(opts =>
            {
                opts.Conventions.Add(new ApplicationDescription("mdesc"));
                opts.Conventions.Add(new ControllerDescription("mctrl"));
            })
...
        }


public class ApplicationDescription : IApplicationModelConvention
    {
        private readonly string _description;

        public ApplicationDescription(string description)
        {
            _description = description;
        }

        public void Apply(ApplicationModel application)
        {
            var basec = application.Controllers[0];
            var cm = new ControllerModel(typeof(MyController).GetTypeInfo(), basec.Attributes);
            application.Controllers.Add(cm);
            application.Properties["description"] = _description;
        }
    }
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: i'm trying to do the same but documentation is lacking. i found a solution using in conjunction with IApplicationFeatureProvider<ControllerFeature> Did you manage to do it only with IApplicationModelConvention

Comment: I did manage to do it, seems to work pretty fine, let me know if you are interested, ill post it here.

Comment: thanks i managed to use only the IApplicationModelConvention and adding the external dll